# Nothing happen after made changes on Flask app in server using uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

how to refresh Flask app on the server after made changes it?

Already saving for the new Flask app code on the folder. But, nothing happens.

After run dah IP address, it gives the same as previous.

What should I need to do to reload/refresh?

Comment: have you tried to restart `uwsgi` service?

Answer (score 0):

It you are using `.ini` configuration files, you can do:

```
touch /path/to/file.ini
```

Have a look at uwsgi [emperor](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html) mode.